# Filtration Performance Variable

Tags: data-transformation, model-evaluation

Update 7/26/23

Sorry for the lack of data in the original post. I put together a dummy data set in the image below.  In this case the target for contaminant out is ~2, although there are diminishing returns at less than 2.  I'd like to come up with a single variable to describe the relationship between contaminant in and contaminant out so that it can be used in a regression model.  Percent reduction is most often used; however, the contaminant out is linearly related, so it doesn't describe the situation very well.

For example, Rows 14 and 29 have nearly the same %reduction.  However, the "performance" variable would need to penalize Row 29 because the contaminant out is still 3.9.  The higher contaminant in of 47.2 should improve the "performance" variable some since the filter must work harder to remove material down to 2; but that is not as important as the reduction closer to 2.

I thought about using the delta alone, however, row 29 is another good example here.  The %reduction and delta are both high, but the contaminant out of 2 should still penalize it relative to others. Due to the nature of the process, the contaminant out will approach 0 asymptotically.  There are diminishing returns as far as inputs in the model for values less than 2, but the "performance" almost exponentially decrease as the contaminant out gets above 2.

[image: Dummy Data Set]

[Original Post]

I'm working on a filtration process and would like to develop a single variable that can be used to describe the performance of the process; however, I believe some type of transformation will be necessary.  I've tried a few log/exponential transformations but can't find one that works well.  I was wondering if anyone here has any suggestions?

In general, the unfiltered material can come in with 30-100 ppm contaminant.  The goal is to get to the low single digit numbers for the contaminant; let's use 1 ppm for the example here. The filtration gets more and more difficult, so the concentration of contaminant in the filtered sample is not linearly related to the input variables (filter variables). Traditionally everything is reported in % reduction, however this doesn't generally do a good job of describing the situation.  For example, 2 ppm remaining in a 100-ppm starting material and 1 ppm remaining in a 50-ppm starting material would both indicate a 98% reduction.  The reduction to 1 ppm, however, is most important.  I also thought about using only the end value for analysis, however, the starting content needs to be included somehow as the treatment needs to account for the higher incoming contaminant load (although it shouldn't be as much of a factor as the outgoing contaminant).  Any suggestions on a transformation or something similar that can be used to help compare performance of the filters?

Comment: Please tell us about the data you are collecting.  If we don't know what they are, we haven't much hope of suggesting a way of analyzing them!  We also need to know what you mean by "describe the performance," because at present you have only told us what you *don't* want in a description.

Comment: I must be missing something important.  "The contaminant out is linearly related, so it doesn't describe the situation very well" sounds like a *great* description of a relationship for any kind of regression model.  In what sense does that not work?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  It should read "is not" linearly related.

Comment: Simulation is one approach for this comparison. There are many ways of implementing this including 1) *hard* simulation. This involves use of some iterative, approximating algorithm such as the bootstrap and successively sampling and resampling the raw data inputs into a model to build up a new dataset of predictions. By averaging across the filters, one gets a sense of how their performance differs vs the target. 2) Modeled simulation. Given a regression model, by iteratively manipulating the parameters  (without data), build up a set of predictions which are, again, averaged by filter.